# Why Is Alloy not an Answer Set Programming system?

Tags: sat-solvers, answer-set-programming

[Alloy's front page](http://alloy.mit.edu/alloy/) doesn't mention ASP, but the description sounds like ASP (finding solutions consistent with a logical spec).  And Alloy isn't listed in the [Wikipedia ASP article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Answer_set_programming).  Yet ASP systems and Alloy both seem to built on top of SAT solvers.  So how do they differ?

[edit: Would it be fair to say, for example, that Alloy is ASP extended with a pile of useful built-in abstractions that make it more useful for writing and checking specs?  Or are there things that Alloy can do that ASP cannot?]